# MySQL SP does not return result? Variable issue?

Tags: mysql

A quick question: I have moved a database over from MSSQL to MySQL, and I am right now converting the Stored Procedures. However, this one does not seem to run properly when executes (I can CREATE it, but when I run it I get no result):

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `Employee_GetAll`(
IN community_id int,
IN search varchar(255)
)
BEGIN

select e.*, er.name as rolename, er.access_level as accesslevel from Employee e
inner join Employee_Role er on e.employee_role = er.id
where e.community_id = community_id
and (firstname like ('%' + search + '%') or lastname like ('%' + search + '%'));

END
```

So, I can create it, but no result is give when I run it. If I run this code...

```
select e.*, er.name as rolename, er.access_level as accesslevel from Employee e
inner join Employee_Role er on e.employee_role = er.id
where e.community_id = 1
and (firstname like ('%do%') or lastname like ('%do%'));
```

... then it runs fine. So, am I doing something wrong with the SEARCH variable? I'm new to MySQL, and trying to wing it a bit.

Regards,

Bob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few issues:

1. Don't give parameters the same names as column names
2. Use `CONCAT()` to build a pattern for `LIKE`.
3. Since it's a one statement procedure you don't need to use `BEGIN...END` block and change `DELIMITER`

That being said try it this way

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `Employee_GetAll`(
  IN _community_id INT,
  IN _search VARCHAR(255)
)
SELECT e.*, er.name AS rolename, er.access_level AS accesslevel 
 FROM Employee e JOIN Employee_Role er 
   ON e.employee_role = er.id
 WHERE e.community_id = _community_id
   AND (firstname LIKE CONCAT('%', _search, '%') OR 
        lastname  LIKE CONCAT('%', _search, '%'));
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0fe50/2)** demo

Comment: Ok, that did it! Thanks! Didn't see the commas in the CONCAT statement there.